# XSLT calculations of nodes

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following input xml:

```
<Input>
  <Incomes>
    <Income>
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Amount>10000</Amount>
    </Income>
    <Income>
      <Year>2017</Year>
      <Amount>20000</Amount>
    </Income>
    <Income>
      <Year>2018</Year>
      <Amount>30000</Amount>
    </Income>
  </Incomes>
  <Expenses>
    <Expense>
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Amount>2000</Amount>
    </Expense>
    <Expense>
      <Year>2017</Year>
      <Amount>5000</Amount>
    </Expense>
    <Expense>
      <Year>2018</Year>
      <Amount>10000</Amount>
    </Expense>
  </Expenses>
</Input>
```

I would like to transform it to the following output xml using xslt:

```
<Output>
  <Savings>
    <Saving>
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Amount>8000</Amount>
      <!-- Income of 2016 - Expense of 2016 -->
    </Saving>
    <Saving>
      <Year>2017</Year>
      <Amount>15000</Amount>
      <!-- Income of 2017 - Expense of 2017 -->
    </Saving>
    <Saving>
      <Year>2018</Year>
      <Amount>20000</Amount>
    </Saving>
  </Savings>
  <CumulativeSavings>
    <CumulativeSaving>
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Amount>8000</Amount><!-- Income of 2016 - Expense of 2016 -->
    </CumulativeSaving>
    <CumulativeSaving>
      <Year>2017</Year>
      <Amount>23000</Amount><!-- Income of 2017 - Expense of 2017 + Cumulative Saving of 2016 -->
    </CumulativeSaving>
    <CumulativeSaving>
      <Year>2018</Year>
      <Amount>43000</Amount><!-- Income of 2018 - Expense of 2018 + Cumulative Saving of 2017 -->
    </CumulativeSaving>
  </CumulativeSavings>
</Output>
```

I am using `<xsl:for-each select="">` to loop through all Incomes, Expenses however I am not sure how I can perform Income - Expense calculation. Also, I need Cumulative Saving as shown in the output xml.

Comment: Well, the question is tagged as XSLT 2 so you can group, you can store result in a variable and reprocess them using apply-templates easily. Grouping is covered in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/xslt-grouping/info so that there to group by year and compute the differences (i.e. the `Savings` part), then push that through templates summing up the grouped Amounts for each year.

Comment: Will there always be the same number of `Income` and `Expenses` elements? It would also help if you edit your question to show your current XSLT. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, it will have the same number of Income and Expense elements.

Comment: @TimC, Even if there are unmatched `Income` , `Expense` elements, the wanted result can still be produced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a more generic solution that will work even with different number of `Income` and `Expense` elements -- `Income` that is unmatched by an `Expense` for the same year, `Expense` that is unmatched by an `Income` for the same year, or even multiple `Income` and/or `Expense` elements -- matched or unmatched -- for the same year.

It also uses **[FXSL-2](https://sourceforge.net/projects/fxsl/)** and its function `f:scanl()`, which calculates the running totals (One can read more about FXSL [**here**](https://fxsl.sf.net) and [**here**](http://conferences.idealliance.org/extreme/html/2006/Novatchev01/EML2006Novatchev01.html)).

Thus, the computation of the running totals from the already calculated savings is expressed just in this single line of code:

```
<xsl:variable name="vCumulatives" select="f:scanl1(f:add(), $vSavingsResult/*/Amount)"/>
```

**Here is the complete transformation** (replace the value of @href in the two `<xsl:import>` directives with your corresponding local paths to the referenced FXLS stylesheets):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:f="http://fxsl.sf.net/"
  exclude-result-prefixes="xs f">
  <xsl:import href="file:///C:/CVS-DDN/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-scanl.xsl"/>
  <xsl:import href="file:///C:/CVS-DDN/fxsl-xslt2/f/func-Operators.xsl"/>

 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:key name="kIncomeByYear" match="Income" use="Year"/>
 <xsl:key name="kExpenseByYear" match="Expense" use="Year"/>

  <xsl:template match="node()|@*" mode="#default savings cumulative">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" mode="#current"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/*[Incomes/Income | Expenses/Expense]">
    <xsl:variable name="vSavingsResult">
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="savings" select=
        "*/Income[generate-id() = generate-id(key('kIncomeByYear', Year)[1])]
       | */Expense[not(key('kIncomeByYear', Year))
                  and generate-id() = generate-id(key('kExpenseByYear', Year)[1])]">
             <xsl:sort select="Year"/>
       </xsl:apply-templates>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="vCumulatives" select="f:scanl1(f:add(), $vSavingsResult/*/Amount)"/>

    <Output>
      <Savings>
        <xsl:sequence select="$vSavingsResult/*"/>
      </Savings>
      <CumulativeSavings>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="$vSavingsResult/*" mode="cumulative">
          <xsl:with-param name="pCumulatives" select="$vCumulatives" tunnel="yes"/>
        </xsl:apply-templates>
      </CumulativeSavings>
    </Output>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Income | Expense" mode="savings">
    <Saving>
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/>
    </Saving>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Amount" mode="savings">
    <Amount>
      <xsl:value-of select=
      "sum(key('kIncomeByYear', ../Year)/Amount) 
     - sum(key('kExpenseByYear', ../Year)/Amount)"/>
    </Amount>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Saving" mode="cumulative">
    <CumulativeSaving><xsl:apply-templates mode="#current"/></CumulativeSaving>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Amount" mode="cumulative">
    <xsl:param name="pCumulatives" tunnel="yes"/>
    <xsl:variable name="vSavingsPos" select="count(../preceding-sibling::*) +1"/>
    <Amount><xsl:value-of select="$pCumulatives[$vSavingsPos]"/></Amount>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Input>
  <Incomes>
    <Income>
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Amount>10000</Amount>
    </Income>
    <Income>
      <Year>2017</Year>
      <Amount>20000</Amount>
    </Income>
    <Income>
      <Year>2018</Year>
      <Amount>30000</Amount>
    </Income>
  </Incomes>
  <Expenses>
    <Expense>
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Amount>2000</Amount>
    </Expense>
    <Expense>
      <Year>2017</Year>
      <Amount>5000</Amount>
    </Expense>
    <Expense>
      <Year>2018</Year>
      <Amount>10000</Amount>
    </Expense>
  </Expenses>
</Input>
```

the wanted, correct result is produced:

```
<Output>
   <Savings>
      <Saving>
         <Year>2016</Year>
         <Amount>8000</Amount>
      </Saving>
      <Saving>
         <Year>2017</Year>
         <Amount>15000</Amount>
      </Saving>
      <Saving>
         <Year>2018</Year>
         <Amount>20000</Amount>
      </Saving>
   </Savings>
   <CumulativeSavings>
      <CumulativeSaving>
         <Year>2016</Year>
         <Amount>8000</Amount>
      </CumulativeSaving>
      <CumulativeSaving>
         <Year>2017</Year>
         <Amount>23000</Amount>
      </CumulativeSaving>
      <CumulativeSaving>
         <Year>2018</Year>
         <Amount>43000</Amount>
      </CumulativeSaving>
   </CumulativeSavings>
</Output>
```

---

**Here is an XML document that contains unmatched `Income` element** (for year 2014), **and unmatched `Expense` element** (for year 2015):

```
<Input>
  <Incomes>
    <Income>
      <Year>2014</Year>
      <Amount>500</Amount>
    </Income>
    <Income>
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Amount>10000</Amount>
    </Income>
    <Income>
      <Year>2017</Year>
      <Amount>20000</Amount>
    </Income>
    <Income>
      <Year>2018</Year>
      <Amount>30000</Amount>
    </Income>
  </Incomes>
  <Expenses>
    <Expense>
      <Year>2015</Year>
      <Amount>1000</Amount>
    </Expense>
    <Expense>
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Amount>2000</Amount>
    </Expense>
    <Expense>
      <Year>2017</Year>
      <Amount>5000</Amount>
    </Expense>
    <Expense>
      <Year>2018</Year>
      <Amount>10000</Amount>
    </Expense>
  </Expenses>
</Input>
```

**Applying on it the same above transformation produces the correct result**:

```
<Output>
   <Savings>
      <Saving>
         <Year>2014</Year>
         <Amount>500</Amount>
      </Saving>
      <Saving>
         <Year>2015</Year>
         <Amount>-1000</Amount>
      </Saving>
      <Saving>
         <Year>2016</Year>
         <Amount>8000</Amount>
      </Saving>
      <Saving>
         <Year>2017</Year>
         <Amount>15000</Amount>
      </Saving>
      <Saving>
         <Year>2018</Year>
         <Amount>20000</Amount>
      </Saving>
   </Savings>
   <CumulativeSavings>
      <CumulativeSaving>
         <Year>2014</Year>
         <Amount>500</Amount>
      </CumulativeSaving>
      <CumulativeSaving>
         <Year>2015</Year>
         <Amount>-500</Amount>
      </CumulativeSaving>
      <CumulativeSaving>
         <Year>2016</Year>
         <Amount>7500</Amount>
      </CumulativeSaving>
      <CumulativeSaving>
         <Year>2017</Year>
         <Amount>22500</Amount>
      </CumulativeSaving>
      <CumulativeSaving>
         <Year>2018</Year>
         <Amount>42500</Amount>
      </CumulativeSaving>
   </CumulativeSavings>
</Output>
```

---

**Finally, the below XML document contains multiple `Income` and `Expense` elements per year in addition to unmatched `Income` and `Expense` elements**:

```
<Input>
  <Incomes>
    <Income>
      <Year>2014</Year>
      <Amount>100</Amount>
    </Income>
    <Income>
      <Year>2014</Year>
      <Amount>400</Amount>
    </Income>
    <Income>
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Amount>10000</Amount>
    </Income>
    <Income>
      <Year>2017</Year>
      <Amount>20000</Amount>
    </Income>
    <Income>
      <Year>2018</Year>
      <Amount>30000</Amount>
    </Income>
  </Incomes>
  <Expenses>
    <Expense>
      <Year>2015</Year>
      <Amount>500</Amount>
    </Expense>
    <Expense>
      <Year>2015</Year>
      <Amount>500</Amount>
    </Expense>
    <Expense>
      <Year>2016</Year>
      <Amount>2000</Amount>
    </Expense>
    <Expense>
      <Year>2017</Year>
      <Amount>5000</Amount>
    </Expense>
    <Expense>
      <Year>2018</Year>
      <Amount>10000</Amount>
    </Expense>
  </Expenses>
</Input>
```

**Again applying the same transformation on this XML document produces the correct result**:

```
<Output>
   <Savings>
      <Saving>
         <Year>2014</Year>
         <Amount>500</Amount>
      </Saving>
      <Saving>
         <Year>2015</Year>
         <Amount>-1000</Amount>
      </Saving>
      <Saving>
         <Year>2016</Year>
         <Amount>8000</Amount>
      </Saving>
      <Saving>
         <Year>2017</Year>
         <Amount>15000</Amount>
      </Saving>
      <Saving>
         <Year>2018</Year>
         <Amount>20000</Amount>
      </Saving>
   </Savings>
   <CumulativeSavings>
      <CumulativeSaving>
         <Year>2014</Year>
         <Amount>500</Amount>
      </CumulativeSaving>
      <CumulativeSaving>
         <Year>2015</Year>
         <Amount>-500</Amount>
      </CumulativeSaving>
      <CumulativeSaving>
         <Year>2016</Year>
         <Amount>7500</Amount>
      </CumulativeSaving>
      <CumulativeSaving>
         <Year>2017</Year>
         <Amount>22500</Amount>
      </CumulativeSaving>
      <CumulativeSaving>
         <Year>2018</Year>
         <Amount>42500</Amount>
      </CumulativeSaving>
   </CumulativeSavings>
</Output>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a key to look up the expense items

```
<xsl:key name="expenses" match="Expense" use="Year" />
```

Then, for a given `Income` element, you can get the amount like so

```
<xsl:variable name="currentAmount" select="Amount - key('expenses', Year)/Amount" />
```

In terms of getting the cumulative total, you can get the `Income` elements one-at-a-time, with a recursive template, passing the current value to the next call using a parameter, so allow you to output both the `Saving` and `CumulativeSaving` elements. If you store the results of this in a variable, you can then output them separately.

Try this XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
  <xsl:key name="expenses" match="Expense" use="Year" />

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="calcs">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="(//Income)[1]" />
    </xsl:variable>
    <Output>
      <Savings>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$calcs/Saving" />
      </Savings>
      <CumulativeSavings>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$calcs/CumulativeSaving" />
      </CumulativeSavings>
    </Output>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Income">
    <xsl:param name="previousAmount" select="0" />
    <xsl:variable name="currentAmount" select="Amount - key('expenses', Year)/Amount" />
    <xsl:variable name="newAmount" select="$currentAmount + $previousAmount" />
    <Saving>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Year" />
      <Amount>
        <xsl:value-of select="$currentAmount" />
      </Amount>
    </Saving>
    <CumulativeSaving>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Year" />
      <Amount>
        <xsl:value-of select="$newAmount" />
      </Amount>
    </CumulativeSaving>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Income[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="previousAmount" select="$newAmount" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note that in XSLT 3.0, you could use `xsl:iterate` instead of a recursive template. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pPzifqk)